Fetching data from Jikan API. Is there a DUBBED broadcast day data option to be fetched?
I'll try to be as concise as possible. I'm building out an Anime watchlist & weekly scheduling webpage/app using React and fetching the Anime data using Jikan API.
I have my weekly watchlist/schedule all built out. I watch subbed, and that is the default broadcast day that is fetched, but I want to include a dubbed schedule option as well. I'm not sure I see an option to pull the dubbed broadcast day. Does anyone know if this is possible? (Dubbed SOMETIMES is a few weeks behind, but sometimes is not)
Helpful links:
Jikan API:
[https://jikan.moe/]
Jikan API Documentation (searching anime by ID):
[https://docs.api.jikan.moe/#tag/anime/operation/getAnimeById]
Myanimelist (where Jikan API pulls it's data from:
[https://animeschedule.net/]
Thanks for any help, and if you need more context, let me know
I've worked through the Jikan API documentation and I don't see a dubbed filtering option. I could manually convert the broadcast day, or manually make it 2 episodes behind but this is not a practial solution because dubbed is not always two weeks behind subbed.
It's also possible that this is not an option, but I just wanted a second set of eyes to make sure.
Thanks for all help!
